# React & Chartjs: How can I best destroy my chart when re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, destroy

Is there a best practice for destroying chartjs charts in React?

I've tried setting state, destroying charts, removing references, conditionally rendering based on chart existing & nothing seems to work. I have a common occurring problem where the new chart simply overlays over the old one.

What's the best move here?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Declare chart variable outside of class component
2. Run the build chart fn on both componentDidMount & componentDidUpdate
3. In each build call the destroy() method on the chart variable if not undefined

Found the solution here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/customizing-chart-js-in-react-2199fa81530a

Comment: Could you show the code to this? I'm running into the same issue and can't get the charts to destroy, I'm creating them based on data coming over from an api, it cycles and updates the line charts, but if the next one doesn't have data, it won't destroy and just shows the previous chart data. i'm also using Functional components instead of class

Comment: My solution was to have a `buildChart` fn that I run on mount, and then I call it every time I need to update the chart. So it looks like this:

`buildChart = () => {
    if (typeof myChart !== "undefined") myChart.destroy();
// do my chart building
}`

you can see it in this repo, but I must warn you the code is awful: https://github.com/crevulus/price-comparison/blob/master/price-comparison-frontend/src/components/SidePanel.js

Comment: Ok makes sense. Yeah I'm wondering if I need to change from Functional to Class Components and reformat my code to accomodate this. Thanks for the reply!